# How to create new pubsubhub rss from existing "normal" rss?

Tags: python, rss, pypi, websub

I'd like to create a new real-time RSS feed using pubsubhubbub by processing an existing RSS feed which i cannot easily change.  Is there a tool or approach which makes this easy?  The RSS feed which i want to process does not offer pubsubhubbub links and i assume i have to poll every N seconds. Is there a readymade solution or example for this, preferably in Python?  (In case you are interested i'd like to have a real-time feed of pypi.python.org updates, consumable by arbitrary other servers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MvL's slides](http://www.zope.de/tagung/Dresden_2010/shop-apis_mvl.pdf) of his talk at Zope Tagung 2010 (page 19) PyPI publishes the feed with the changes of the last [hour](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=lasthour) on http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com.

Also see http://mail.python.org/pipermail/catalog-sig/2012-July/004551.html

Comment: a good start, but why only once per hour?  Isn't pubsubhubbub bout real time?

Comment: What I meant is that the feed shows the releases of the last hour. The PuSH hub is notified by the PyPI code automatically when a change occurs (https://bitbucket.org/loewis/pypi/src/7ffa1f091b87dd58eb3770abc6af30ec37943ba1/store.py?at=default#cl-2159), which then pulls that feed and provides any PuSH subscriber with a real time notification.

Answer (score 2):

The only option I know of (excluding writing your own) is http://superfeedr.com/, but seems that they are billing subscribers too, at least on platforms they don't host.

Comment: Hi, I created http://superfeedr.com . We do indeed host hubs, and subscription to these hubs is free :) However, for non pubsubhubbub enabled feeds, you'll have to pay us, but we charge less than what it'd cost you to achieve this.